# Finite element simulation of Airy waves

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am attempting to solve for waves on a water surface starting with a two dimensional solution. The equations are that the water must satisfy Laplace's equation everywhere with a time dependent boundary condition on the top surface. The equations are

$$\begin{align*}
&\nabla^2\phi=0\\
&\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}+\frac1{g}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}\right)_{y=y_2}=0
\end{align*}$$

where $x$ is horizontal and $y$ vertical; also, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. The second equation applies at the surface. The first term in this equation is the vertical gradient so I think I can use a Neumann condition to enter this equation.

So I start by making a grid.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
x2 = 4; y2 = 1;
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= x2 && 0 <= y <= y2, {x, y}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"Continuation"},
    MaxCellMeasure -> .002, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I now make some initial conditions. I have worked out an initial velocity for the top surface and solve to give the initial value of the potential function.

```
a = 0.40825787026798765;
b = 0.1689925306573793;
g = 9.81;

solIC = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[ϕ0[x, y], {x, y}] ==
     NeumannValue[-b (E^-(x - 1)^2 - a), 0 <= x <= x2 && y == y2],
    DirichletCondition[ϕ0[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0]
    }, ϕ0, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
```

The velocity on the surface and throughout the water looks reasonable.

```
Plot[Evaluate[(D[solIC[x, y], y]) /. y -> y2], {x, 0, x2}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/4]
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, y_] := Evaluate[Grad[solIC[x, y], {x, y}, "Cartesian"]];
StreamPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, x2}, {y, 0, y2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I attempt to set up the time dependent problem.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   Laplacian[ϕ[x, y, t], {x, y}] ==
    NeumannValue[1/g Derivative[0, 0, 2][ϕ][x, y, t], 
     0 <= x <= x2 && y == y2],
   DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y, t] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0],
   ϕ[x, y, 0] == solIC[x, y]
   }, ϕ,
  {x, y} ∈ mesh, {t, 0, 0.1}
  ]
```

This does not work and gives me the error

> ```
> CoefficientArrays::poly: ϕ$1664+ϕ$1665-NeumannValue[0.101937 ϕ$1666,0<=x<=4&&y==1] 
> is not a polynomial. >>
> ```

Now I am stuck. This does not help. Any suggestions?

**Suggestions from comments**

1. If I put in a time derivative in the equation this gives the same error.
2. If I take the time derivative out of the `NeumannValue` and put a time derivative into the equation then it solves but is meaningless. Does this suggest we can't have time derivatives in the boundary conditions?

Can you suggest how we might set up an alternative equation who's solution might go into the boundary condition?

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[ϕ[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 0.1 D[ϕ[x, y, t], t] +
      NeumannValue[ϕ[x, y, t], 0 <= x <= x2 && y == y2],
    DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y, t] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0],
    ϕ[x, y, 0] == solIC[x, y]
    }, ϕ,
   {x, y} ∈ mesh, {t, 0, 0.1}
   ];
Plot3D[sol[x, y2, t], {x, 0, x2}, {t, 0, 0.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the problem could be the derivative in the `NeumannValue`.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but it seems that the equation is not of the type supported by Mma, just for the reason that the time derivative only enters the Neumann condition, but not the equation itself. May be one could try to add the first derivative multiplied by some factor to the equation as a regularization. And then try to get this factor down?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I added in a time derivative to the equation and got the same error. So no progress.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Let's ignore the NeumannValue for a second, should there not be a `Derivative[0, 0, 1][\[Phi]][x, y, t]` or `D[\[Phi][x, y, t], {t, 1}]` in the time dependent equation? Also is this a wave equation? (second order time deriv? - but maybe the title is miss leading me here.)

Comment: If you want to solve a time dependent problem you'd need to set a time derivative for the dependent variable. I am not sure if not doing so has a meaning. Now, for time derivatives in NeumannValues those, to the best of my knowledge, only make sense for wave equations (or higher order time derivatives) and that can be done. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user21 I have edited the original post and put the textbook equations in to show what I am doing. I agree it is odd to have no time dependence in the main equation but that is the way the formulation goes. Perhaps I need to get this into the main equation as a subsidiary equation.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hm, never seen something like this. Could you tell me what the text book is? One additional thought. For a second order time derivative (wave eqn.) we need initial position + initial velocities. For a first order time derivative we'd need a initial condition - for no time derivative we'd not even need an initial condition....  so how would time even propagate?

Comment: You mention that you'd use a Neumann value for the first term in the second equation. But a Neumann values addresses n.(d/dx+d/dy) - there is no d/dx in this case. Hm... very strange. What method is proposed in the text book?

Comment: @user21 The text book is: Landau and Lifshitz, Course of Theoretical Physics, Fluid Mechanics 1987 page 32. They do analytical solutions. It is a linearised equation. I also found it here http://web.mit.edu/2.20/www/lectures/lec14/lecture14.pdf in section 6.2.1.

Comment: Puh, I don't know. You could try solving it as a coupled system. [Airy wave theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_wave_theory) with phi and eta - not sure.

Comment: @Hugh, I think I am going to delete my answer to make room for a new one (which I do not have but perhaps some else has) Objections?

Comment: @user21 I think keep it. It might inspire and you warn that it is not an answer. The problem is -how do we provoke an answer from those that might know?

Comment: @Hugh, I have an idea :-)

Comment: @Hugh, I hope that is enough incentive for someone to come up with an idea.

Comment: You're trying to obtain the same solution as the one in p32 of the book by setting appropriate i.c. and b.c., or just want to solve the equation under the i.c. and b.c. given in your question? Do you just need a solution by FEM i.e. analytic approaches and other numeric approaches are not concerned?

Comment: @xzczd I need to do more complicated problems that in the book. For example a moving wall as a paddle. FE is essential, I don't think there are analytic solutions.

Comment: @Hugh, unfortunately, the bounty did not draw anther solution. Too bad.

Comment: @user21   Well done for trying.  I am going to contact some specialists to see if there are better formulations.

Answer (score 16):

**Update**: When I wrote this answer it was not clear to me that this question is about [Airy wave theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_wave_theory) which I do not know how to solve.

**Old answer**:

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but here is a time dependent solution. We can take it from here if it's not what you need.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{1/g D[ϕ[x, y, t], {t, 1}] - 
      Laplacian[ϕ[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y, t] == 0, 
     x == 0 && y == 0], ϕ[x, y, 0] == solIC[x, y]}, ϕ, {x, 
     y} ∈ mesh, {t, 0, 0.1}];
Plot3D[Evaluate[{sol[x, y, 0], sol[x, y, 0.1]}], {x, y} ∈ 
  mesh, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You can have derivatives of time in the NeumannValue - but that needs to be a wave type of equation:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{1/g D[ϕ[x, y, t], {t, 2}] - 
      Laplacian[ϕ[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 
     NeumannValue[-Derivative[0, 0, 1][ϕ][x, y, t], 
      0 <= x <= x2 && y == y2], 
    DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y, t] == 0, 
     x == 0 && y == 0], ϕ[x, y, 0] == solIC[x, y], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][ϕ][x, y, 0] == 0}, ϕ, {x, 
     y} ∈ mesh, {t, 0, 0.1}];
```

For this example, however, you'd need to set up an initial velocity that makes sense. Setting it to zero is not correct.

Here is a simplified example of how to set time derivatives within the NeumannValue. This is in essence an absorbing boundary condition (Note, that in this 1D case there is a small bug that will be fixed in a upcoming version, the sign in the NeumannValue is not correct. This has no effect on the 2D case you are looking at):

```
eqn = D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] == 
   D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
    NeumannValue[
     If[$VersionNumber <= 10.4, 1, -1]*Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x], 
     x == 0 || x == 1];
u0[x_] := Evaluate[D[0.125 Erf[(x - 0.5)/0.125], x]];
ic = {u[0, x] == u0[x], Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
list = Table[
   Plot[ufun[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1.3}], {t, 0, 1, 
    0.1}];
ListAnimate[list]
```

[image]