# Solving a wave equation over the Black Sea shaped region

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, geography

There is a code for solving a wave equation over an arbitrarily shaped region.

```
Ω = 
 RegionDifference[RegionUnion[Disk[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]], 
 Disk[{1/4, 1/4}, 1/5]];

uifWave = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t, t] - Inactive[Laplacian][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
   u[0, x, y] == E^(-5*((x - 3/2)^2 + (y - 3/2)^2)), 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0, 
 DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, 
     True]}, 
        u, {t, 0, 2 π}, {x, y} ∈ Ω] // 
    Quiet;

framesWEQ = 
 Table[Plot3D[
 uifWave[t, x, y], {x, y} ∈ uifWave["ElementMesh"], 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None], {t, 0, 2 π, 2 π/50}];




  Manipulate[framesWEQ[[i]], {{i, 16, "time"}, 1, Length[framesWEQ], 1},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

How to solve this  equation over the Black Sea shape region?

```
 mask = GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[RGBColor["Aqua"]], 
 Polygon[Entity["Ocean", "BlackSea"]]}, GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Ω = 
 DiscretizeRegion[
  Entity["Ocean", "BlackSea"]["Polygon"] /. GeoPosition -> Identity]

Comment: Somehow the answer seems trivially obvious.  Could you say more about the problem you're facing?

Comment: @Edmund That, like my `Ω = Cases[mask, _Polygon, Infinity][[1]]`, doesn't work. I mean, it produces a region, but does not produce a solution to the equations.

Comment: Might need `{x, y} ∈ Ω` in `Plot3D` instead of `"ElementMesh"`.

Comment: @corey979 I get a solution for `uifWave` that plots but I think the wave is very small over the area. May need to increase the amplitude in `u`.

Comment: related: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/853228

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use something like this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
dg = DiscretizeGraphics[
   Entity["Ocean", "BlackSea"]["Polygon"] /. 
    GeoPosition -> Identity];
mesh = ToElementMesh[dg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005 (*, "MeshOrder"->1 *)]
```

You will be able to refine the mesh to your needs. This will then do the time integration and monitor it's progress:

```
Monitor[uifWave = 
  NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t, t] - 
      Inactive[Laplacian][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    u[0, x, y] == Exp[-10 ((x - 44)^2 + (y - 31)^2)], 
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], monitor]
```

For completeness:

```
framesWEQ = 
  Table[Plot3D[uifWave[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] dg, 
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    Mesh -> None], {t, 0, 2, 2/50}];
Manipulate[framesWEQ[[i]], {{i, 16, "time"}, 1, Length[framesWEQ], 1},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Answer (score 9):

It works with [Edmund](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund)'s suggestion, only the initial state is changed to

`u[0, x, y] == Exp[-10 ((x - 44)^2 + (y - 31)^2)]`.

Coordinates `{44, 31}` are inside the Black Sea.

For the sake of simplicity I've restricted the region to the western third of the sea.

```
Ω =  DiscretizeRegion[Entity["Ocean", "BlackSea"]["Polygon"] /. GeoPosition -> Identity,
     {{40, 50}, {27, 33}}]
```

[image]

Here is the solution for `{t,0,4}`:

[image]

**EDIT**: Another gif with 100 frames and `PlotPoints -> 50`

[image]

Comment: Looks like the wavelength is too short for the granularity of the discretization ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, an accurate solution needs some tweaking :)

Comment: Just being picky; these are membrane waves. We need to solve for water surface waves which we don't know how to do yet see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/122063/12558).